# Executing a task after all test are launch cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress

I need to execute some code after all tests run. I add this test on after hook. But this task needs the report to be created, but on after hook, the report is not created yet.

I also tried to use

```
 on('run:end', () => {
        console.log("gdfgfdsafkañjsdfjñaldfkjsñkasfdñlassfjdskafmjassd");
  });
```

but it does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/818) for that.

At the moment you can only leverage a `package.json` [`post` hook](https://medium.com/yld-engineering-blog/using-npm-pre-and-post-hooks-d89dcf2d86cf). So, if you have a dedicated command in your `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
  "cy:run": "cypress run"
}
```

you can add a `postcy:run` script

```
"scripts": {
  "cy:run": "cypress run",
  "postcy:run": "<YOUR_COMMAND>"
}
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid this solution. I will wait for more answers but if I don't find another one, I will accept yours.

Answer (score 5):

You can now listen to `after:run` events in the plugins file:

```
on('after:run', (results) => { /* ... */ })
```

The event fires after the run.

See more info at [After Run API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api.html#Syntax)

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the `post` hook might not run when the tests fail. I'm currently using a global `after` hook in `support/index.ts` for running after all tests

I'm currently using a global `after` hook in `support/index.ts`

```
after(() => {
  // something here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the global after is executed before the test report is done, so it is not a good solution for me.

Comment: Can `wait` be used until the report gets generated?

Comment: The reports don't end until the whole process finishes including the after hooks, so I had to the first solution on this post.