# How to run cy.task after all siutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, automated-tests, cypress

Can you tell me how I can run cy.task after run all test siutes? I generate file at the beginning of the tests, and I want to remove it after they will be finished, without care that all/any passed or failed I want to run cy.task just after finish cypress run execute

Comment: similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006940/executing-a-task-after-all-test-are-launch-cypress)

Comment: @PRAJINPRAKASH thansk, I will try. Can you tell me, how I can check what kind of events Cypress emits? Like test:after:run, run:end and others?

Comment: use [this](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html) documentation

Comment: @PRAJINPRAKASH It not working wih run:end, and not working with post in package json

`"scripts": {
   "cy:lol": "cypress run",
   "postcy:lol": "cy.task('deleteFile')",
  }`
Is it ok? cy.task('deleteFile') works good inside tests

Answer (score 0):

As of Cypress 6.2.0, you can listen to the `after:run` event in the plugins file and run any piece of code you'd like within that event handler.

*This feature is currently experimental and requires setting the `experimentalRunEvents` configuration option to `true`.

See the `after:run` API doc for more details: https://on.cypress.io/after-run-api